# Non-interactively write to the registry without overwriting

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, registry

I'm trying to use the [`reg add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add) command (reg.exe) to write to the registry, but if the value already exists I don't want to overwrite it. Without the `/f` option it asks for confirmation, which I don't want. With `/f` it overwrites the value, which I also don't want.

Is there an easy way to add a registry value if it doesn't exist but leave it alone if it does, and *not* prompt the user?

Comment: Have you considered or tried piping `N` to the confirmation request. e.g. `Echo N|Reg Add ...`

Comment: What about first checking with `reg query`  if the value exists?

Comment: @Compo That works, but I add `> nul` to the end so it doesn't say it was canceled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment…

Because you have reported having to decline the overwrite prompt, I would suggest you pipe the expected `N` into your `REG` command:

```bat
Echo N|Reg Add "HK…… >Nul
```

Answer (score 0):

As reg returns errorlevels it can be as simple as
(using conditional execution on `&&` success or `||` fail )

```
reg query "hkcu\console" /V ColorTable15 >NUL 2>&1  &&( echo Val exists) ||(echo Val not there)
Val exists

reg query "hkcu\console" /V ColorTable16 >NUL 2>&1  &&( echo Val exists) ||(echo Val not there)
Val not there
```